# Frameworks para efetuar testes em aplicação Android e Webservice

Tags: android, web-service, testes

Boa tarde pessoal, gostaria de saber quais frameworks poderia utilizar para efetuar os seguintes teste:

Aplicação Android:

- Teste Unitário
- Teste de Estresse

Web service

- Teste Unitário
- Análise Estática

Answer (score 0):

Opa colega!! 
Para testes unitários em Android você pode usar o Android Testing Framework, mas existem várias ferramentas de automação, é só dar uma pesquisada rápida na web. Já para testes de performance em geral para Android não sei qual ferramenta atende a esse propósito e ainda não vi nenhum conteúdo na web tratando dessa abordagem para app Android.
Com relação a web services você pode fazer testes unitários com JUnit que é de longe o mais usado, mas tem muitas outras ferramentas, é só pesquisar. Para análise estática da uma olhada nesse site que sugere algumas ferramentas: http://www.matera.com/br/2013/07/30/ferramentas-de-apoio-na-busca-pela-qualidade-do-codigo/